# For OOP, are immutable and invariant synonymous?

Tags: oop, immutability, invariants

For OOP, are immutable and invariant synonymous?

I have a vague feeling that a difference exists, but I'm not sure.

I believe that immutable typically is applied to objects, while invariant is typically applied to attributes/values.

In both cases the object or variable would remain unmodified and "true", so they seem to be very similar.

Thanks for any feedback as I am trying to improve the precision of my understanding of these terms, and I think I am overlooking the subtle differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if those are correct definitions, but for me "immutable" means that a data structure does not change, while an "invariant" is a set condition that does not change and remains true <strike>(but it is not related to a specific instance of data)</strike>.

Now using immutable data structures helps to ensure that invariants remain true, since they don't mutate they will not just suddenly break an invariant that was true before.

Comment: +1 as it basicly sums it up except that both relate to a specific instance of data.

Comment: Some examples of invariants are: is_positive, x.is_positive implies y.is_positive, colour.is_blueish

Answer (score 1):

Immutable refers to an object not changing during it's lifetime.

- An immutable string. If you concatenate, it creates a new string. The original one is unchanged.

Invariants are guarantees that don't change for a specified duration. They do not have to  explicitly exist as attributes or values.

- Object must be in a valid state at all times.
- Object must be in state-X to perform operation-Y.
- If the operation-X is called, the object is guaranteed to be in state-X.
- Entity can be a Company or a Person, but cannot be both at the same time.
- A file cannot be both opened and closed at the same time.

Comment: -1 as don't understand the bit about invariants ( and I know what they are). And duration has nothing to do with it, unless it is a time related invariant.